# In bash, how do I bind a function key to a command?

Tags: bash, shell, binding

Example:  I want to bind the <kbd>F12</kbd> key to the command `echo "foobar"` such that every time I hit <kbd>F12</kbd> the message "foobar" will be printed to screen.  Ideally it could be any arbitrary shell command, not just builtins.  How does one go about this?

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You can determine the character sequence emitted by a key by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> at the command line, then pressing the key you're interested in. On my system for <kbd>F12</kbd>, I get `^[[24~`. The `^[` represents <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Different types of terminals or terminal emulators can emit different codes for the same key.

At a Bash prompt you can enter a command like this to enable the key macro so you can try it out.

```
bind '"\e[24~":"foobar"'
```

Now, when you press <kbd>F12</kbd>, you'll get "foobar" on the command line ready for further editing. If you wanted a keystroke to enter a command immediately, you can add a newline:

```
bind '"\e[24~":"pwd\n"'
```

Now when you press <kbd>F12</kbd>, you'll get the current directory displayed without having to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. What if you've already typed something on the line and you use this which automatically executes? It could get messy. However, you could clear the line as part of your macro:

```
bind '"\e[24~":"\C-k \C-upwd\n"'
```

The space makes sure that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd> has something to delete to keep the bell from ringing.

Once you've gotten the macro working the way you want, you can make it persistent by adding it to your `~/.inputrc` file. There's no need for the `bind` command or the outer set of single quotes:

```
"\e[24~":"\C-k \C-upwd\n"
```

**Edit:**

You can also create a key binding that will execute something without disturbing the current command line.

```
bind -x '"\eW":"who"'
```

Then while you're typing a command that requires a username, for example, and you need to know the names of user who are logged in, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> and the output of `who` will be displayed and the prompt will be re-issued with your partial command intact and the cursor in the same position in the line.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work properly for keys such as <kbd>F12</kbd> which output more than two characters. In some cases this can be worked around.

The command (`who` in this case) could be any executable - a program, script or function.

Comment: What if i want to add a binding to "ctrl+q"?

Comment: @kubudi: `bind '"\C-q": menu-complete'` for example (or in your `~/.inputrc`: `"\C-q": menu-complete`). You may also need `stty -ixon` in your `~/.bashrc` to disable flow control and make ^S and ^Q available.

Comment: You say that `^[` represents `esc` and then you seem to substitute it for `\e` in your example. Could you explain why please?

Comment: @Remover: The `^[` is the output representation. The `\e` is one way to enter it (`^[` doesn't work for that).

Comment: How can I bind "\C-z"? I'd love to get something like what's described for zsh on http://sheerun.net/2014/03/21/how-to-boost-your-vim-productivity/

Comment: How can I **output** (not bind) Ctrl-C (interrupt)? I tried doing bind '"\e[24~":"\C-cpwd\n"' but it just didn't do anything. My goal is, if I have something partially typed, and I press F12, the partially typed command is `^C`ed and the `pwd` command is executed. That way while the partial command is **not** executed, it **remains** on the screen (for my reference). I can do this manually, but I want to do it as bind output for the F12 key.

Comment: BTW, it's `~/.inputrc` not `~/inputrc`. After seeing the answer I created the file without the `.` and was wondering why it doesn't work.

Comment: @ADTC: I fixed the typo in my answer, thanks. One way to do something like what you're trying to do would be to do `bind '"^[[24~":"\C-apwd #\n"'`. This inserts `pwd` and a space and a comment character at the beginning of the line which changes your partially typed command into a comment. Similarly, `bind '"^[[24~":"\e#pwd\n"'` which makes the partially typed command a comment on its own line and the `pwd` executed at a prompt of its own. If you ask this as a separate question and include what you're trying to accomplish, I can post an example that would allow you to do the `pwd` without...

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Thanks! These options to comment the current line are good enough for what I need :) I think I'll prefer the second variant. Oh, maybe you can add them both to your answer :)

Comment: @DennisWilliamson "Unfortunately, this doesn't work properly for keys such as F12 which output more than two characters. In some cases this can be worked around."

Interesting, in my case `bind -x '"\e[24~":"who"'` worked with no difficulty or modification. (Readline 6.3, bash 4.3.11(1).)

Comment: Here is documentation about key binding in GNU readline: https://tiswww.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html

Comment: How can I use this for more complex commands? For instance, I am trying to create a keybinding that will extract a ticket number from my current git branch and paste it. I'm trying:
 `bind -x '"\eb":"git branch --show-current | egrep -o 'ABC-\d+'"'`.
However, this doesn't work because of the quotes around the regular expression. Anyway around this?

Comment: @user1427380: There are two solutions: 1) if you define the binding in your `~/.inputrc` file you only enter the key and command, each in double quotes without the outer  single quotes (or the command and option); 2) you can use escapes for the inner single quotes in the command form, unfortunately it's ugly: `bind -x '"\eb":"git branch --show-current | egrep -o '\''ABC-\d+'\''"'`

Answer (score 22):

You can define bash key bindings in  `~/.inputrc` (configuration file for the GNU Readline library). The syntax is

<keysym or key name>: macro

for example:

```
Control-o: "> output"
```

will create a macro which inserts "> output" when you press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>

```
 "\e[11~": "echo foobar"
```

will create a macro which inserts "echo foobar" when you press <kbd>F1</kbd>... I don't know what the keysym for <kbd>F11</kbd> is off hand.

Edit:

`.inputrc` understands the `\n` escape sequence for linefeed, so you can use

```
 "\e[11~": "echo foobar\n"
```

Which will effectively 'press enter' after the command is issued.

Comment: you can use "\n" within a macro, to add a newline character:

Comment: This works better for me as it defines the key mapping on opening a terminal.

Comment: For `Alt`, use `\e`, e.g. `"\eo": "> output"`.

Comment: For a more in-depth tutorial on using `.inputrc` see https://hackaday.com/2018/01/19/linux-fu-custom-bash-command-completion/

Comment: Where can I find .inputrc file?

Comment: @ArthurHenriqueDellaFraga I've edited the answer; it will be in your home directory. If it doesn't exist, you can create it.

Comment: I made [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59384704/2989289) in head to keep looking about learn more from this subject

Answer (score 7):

This solution is specific to X11 environments and has nothing to do with bash, but adding the following to your .Xmodmaps

```
 % loadkeys
 keycode 88 = F12
 string F12 = "foobar"
 %
```

will send the string "foobar" to the terminal upon hitting F12.

Comment: Keep in mind that this isn't the same as the shell running a command. If you actually want to run a command, you'll have have to hit enter (or have the string sent do that for you). Probably also want to be safe and clear the line first.

Comment: This would be awesome, but it doesn't seem to work as of Fedora 20 anyway. I even tried using xev to find the proper keycode for F12 first (in my case, 96) and using it instead of 88. Neither one works.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to bind `Ctrl+B` to a command. Inspired by an answer above, I tried to use `bind` but could not figure out what series of cryptic squiggles (`\e[24~` ?) translate to `Ctrl+B`.

On a Mac, go to Settings of the Terminal app, Profiles -> Keyboard -> `+` then press the keyboard shortcut you're after and it comes out. For me `Ctrl+B` resulted in `\002` which i successfully bound to command

`bind '"\002":"echo command"'`

Also, if you want the command to be executed right-away (not just inserted in to the prompt), you can add the Enter to the end of your command, like so:

`bind '"\002":"echo command\015"'`