# In Bash, how to bind a key mapping with the variable contents

Tags: bash, bind, keystroke

If I have a variable cmd I want to bind a key with the content of that variable

for example:

```
bind '"\C-h":"$cmd"'
```

but it doesn't work.
How can I do?

Comment: check this posting   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200800/in-bash-how-do-i-bind-a-function-key-to-a-command

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
bind -x '"\C-h":READLINE_LINE="$READLINE_LINE""$cmd"; ((READLINE_POINT += ${#cmd}));'
```

Tested on 4.2, works like a charm. Doesn't work on 3.x though. Hope you enjoy!