# How to set button ESC and F5 using trap?

Tags: bash

How to run a using trap function foo () when you press the "ESC" and function foo2 () when pressing "F5" ? Advise anyone? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try look:

```
man bash | less +'/  bind '
```

EDIT
here an interesting link:
[In bash, how do I bind a function key to a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200800/in-bash-how-do-i-bind-a-function-key-to-a-command)

But ESC key should not be bind because it's used as key escape char; to remove ESC bind :

```
bind -r '\e'
```

After trying it, it seems there is a bug:
http://osdir.com/ml/bug-bash-gnu/2010-07/msg00008.html