# bash/zsh output line in command line

Tags: bash, zsh, shortcut

I have been looking around, but I haven't found any answer so far. I Bash/Zsh, I know of a variation of

```
echo !! 
echo !$
```

and so on. But is there a way to recall the last output line? I know I could simply edit the line and add some piping information but I was wondering whether there were an alternative. To illustrate, I might want to do the following

```
ls -tr
vim {whatever key to recall the last line}
```

which would allow me to edit the most recent file.

If a similar question was already asked and I was unable to find it, could you please redirect me to it?

Comment: no, the shell doesn't keep track of the output of any command, it's not it's job. also, this is probably off topic on SO.

Comment: thanks for your answer mata. I have seen some "similar" enough question on SO, so I thought it would be ok. Might be wrong though...

Comment: If you use `tmux`, you *might* be able to script it to copy the last line of its output buffer. It would not be straightforward, and more work than I can devote to figure out right now. Hopefully, this comment will inspire someone (or my future self) to investigate the details and post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're out of luck. Potentially the shell would have to store a huge amount of info (imagine an long running process and its output).

For your example:

```
ls -tr
vim {whatever key to recall the last line}
```

perhaps an acceptable alternative is to use a subshell thus:

```
ls -tr
vim $(!!)
```

which re-executes your last command in a subshell and the output is used as the argument to `vim`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That could be an option, indeed.

Comment: re- "Potentially the shell would have to store a huge amount of info" That huge amount of info is already stored anyway — it's the visible scroll-back buffer. But that's not in the domain of the shell, rather the terminal.

Comment: The visible scrollback buffer is usually limited, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, there is a way to accomplish your goal. This is just a proof-of-concept, I wouldn't really recommend to do so:

```
> script --flush /tmp/myscript
Script started, file is /tmp/myscript
> LASTLINE() {
     tail -2 /tmp/myscript | head -1 | tr -d '\r'
  }
> bind '"^[[15~":"$(LASTLINE)\n"'
> ls -tr1
file1
file2
fileN
> vi [press F5]
```

The idea: use `script` as the tool which remembers in- and output. In the example, it stores all data in file "/tmp/myscript" which in turn can be read to get the last result line.
Since the actual command (`vi ...`) is the last line in "myscript", we read the last two lines of that file and use the first one of them. (Additionally, I had to filter the return character via `tr`.) Now we bind this command `LASTLINE` to F5 (look at [In bash, how do I bind a function key to a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200800/in-bash-how-do-i-bind-a-function-key-to-a-command) to see in detail how to bind a command to a key).
And from now on, you can press F5 to get the contents of the last output line.

If you do so, remember that you are within a sub-shell (because of `script`) which can be left via `exit` to get back to your original shell.

Careful: this is more or less playing-with-bash. There are race-conditions and other draw-backs, so
 I'd recommend not to use this solution in sensitive environment.