# How can I make a hot-key (eg F9) run a specific command in an already open gnome-terminal?

Tags: hotkeys, gnome-terminal

I use a terminal for just about everything. There are a few commands that I often execute within a directory like:

```
emacs main.tex
evince main.pdf
```

It may seem silly, I'd like to be able to run a set of commands like this with a single keystroke. Is there any way to map (say) `F9` to write a specific sequence of characters to an open gnome terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gnome-terminal doesn't have such a feature, but you might configure bash (actually, readline) to insert a certain string for a given key. Edit `~/.inputrc` or `/etc/inputrc` and add such lines:

```
"\e[19~": "emacs main.tex"
"\e[20~": "evince main.pdf"
```

Watch out: When you press <kbd>F8</kbd> or <kbd>F9</kbd>, these will do exactly the same as if you've typed those characters; no matter what the context is. E.g. if you type `rm` and then press <kbd>space</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you'll remove your `main.tex`!

Comment: Awesome! Is there a way to add a carriage return to the end? Where do you find the escape codes for the f-keys? And can you add modifiers to the keys, like shift-F9?

Comment: Newline can be added as `\n`. To figure out the escape codes (even with modifier), the easiest method is to launch a `cat` command, and then press the desired key. You'll need to replace the initial `^[` by `\e` but the rest stays the same. Note that these sequences might vary across terminals, but if they do, you can add multiple versions to your inputrc.

Comment: I needed to add `$include /etc/inputrc` to the top of my `.inputrc` file to keep the default quick-keys (like C-a taking me to the start of the line).

Comment: "You can determine the character sequence emitted by a key by pressing Ctrl-v..."   See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200800/in-bash-how-do-i-bind-a-function-key-to-a-command