# Bash and readline: how to bind key to a "silent command" of my own in bash?

Tags: bash, libreadline

What I want to do is simple: add a keybinding to one of my program using readline startup file inputrc but, in addition, as my program does not produce any output, I do not want the command name to appear on stdout.

What my problem is:

.inputrc content:

```
"\e[1;5A":'pipe_send\n'
```

When I hit ctrl+uparrow, on the command line appears "pipe_send":

```
[ alexkag@$$$$$:: / ]                                                  
$ pipe_send
```

What I'd like is not having `pipe_send` appear on the command line, just like the commands provided by readline such as history-search-backward, history-search-forward, etc.
Do you know any way to do that? Maybe shoudn't I use readline? Note: my keybinding must only be visible in bash, not to the whole system.

Comment: I don't know much about key binding, but since you have already done some research , I believe this link help you in some way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200800/in-bash-how-do-i-bind-a-function-key-to-a-command

Comment: I guess you want to put this in your `.bashrc`: `bind -x '"\e[1;5A":pipe_send'`.

Comment: I don't know anything about readline programming, but keywords such as `history-search-forward` in `.inputrc` are not quoted. I guess they are kind of constants? However, in your example you quote your command (`pipe_send`) as a string which is weird...

Comment: @cychoi: his "command" is not a keyword. hence the quotes.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Okay, I got it now. He's not using the readline library to write a program which react to the keybindings. Rather, he's using bash to respond to a key press sequence and then bash will output the string to standard output(?) which hopefully can be fed to his program.

Comment: gniourf_gniourf and mainframer are right : bind -x works for me, thank you guys.

Comment: `history-search-forward` is a built-in `readline` function, not a literal string.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments by gniourf_gniourf the solution is:

```
bind -x '"\e[1;5A":pipe_send'
```

`bind -x` will tell bash to execute a command whenever a certain key is pressed:

> `-x keyseq:shell-command`
>
> Cause shell-command to be executed whenever keyseq is entered. When shell-command is executed, the shell sets the READLINE_LINE variable to the contents of the Readline line buffer and the READLINE_POINT variable to the current location of the insertion point. If the executed command changes the value of READLINE_LINE or READLINE_POINT, those new values will be reflected in the editing state.

`\e[1;5A` is the terminal code sent for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd>