# Find out corresponding escape sequence for a given key combo

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, iterm2

In `Emacs`, I want to bind a particular key combination to a command. However, because I am using `Emacs` in terminal mode within `iTerm2` on OS X, I need to translate the key combo to character escape sequence and register that sequence with `iTerm2` so that it will recognize the key combination.

But how do I find out the corresponding sequence given a key combination? For example, I found that something like `^[[1;8A` corresponds to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> (where I have configured <kbd>Alt</kbd> to function as `+Esc` in `iTerm2`), but I have no idea how that key combination translates into this particular sequence.

Is there a way to look up or work out the escape sequence for any given key combo? For example, what is the sequence for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>?

A related question, can someone explain to me the relationship between setting up a key combo with its corresponding sequence in `iTerm2` and making `Emacs` translate a sequence into its internal key representation using `input-decode-map` inside `.emacs` (e.g. `(define-key input-decode-map "[escape_sequencehere]" [internal_key_representation_here]`)? It seems to me that setting it up in `iTerm2` alone is sufficient to make the binding work in `Emacs`, so when and why do we need to set up the latter in `.emacs`? (and perhaps when do we need both to make something work?)

Comment: i assume you've already read through the relevant documentation such as http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS and http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MetaKeyProblems ?

Answer (score 5):

In your terminal type `showkey -a` and let the key-strokes fly.

Comment: You may need to install showkey from homebrew with `brew install showkey`

Answer (score 3):

Some of the key combinations are sent directly to the application running in `iTerm2`. You can get it

- by using `ctrl`+`v` approach (see [In bash, how do I bind a function key to a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200800/in-bash-how-do-i-bind-a-function-key-to-a-command)) or

  ```
  bash-3.2$ ^[[1;10A  (in this case I hit ctrl + v before shift+alt+up)
  ```
- `sed -n l` (note it's lowercase `L`). For instance, you can see what the application receives if you send (`shift`+`alt`+`up`):

  ```
  bash-3.2$ sed -n l
  ^[[1;10A
  \033[1;10A$
  ```

If some key combination does not get through, you can instruct `iTerm2` to [let it pass](https://superuser.com/a/740174/518332) and map it to a key combination that you can detect as described above. 
For instance, you can send through and map `ctrl`+`alt`+`cmd`+`R` to `ESC+sdf` and your terminal will receive `^[sdf` which you can assign to a command in Emacs.