# Bash: Reevaluate PS1 without carriage return

Tags: linux, bash, prompt

Here is my PS1:

```
export PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

Which looks like this:

```
user@ubuntu:~/ $
```

I have bound Alt+{Left,Right} Arrow to command that change the current working directory:

```
bind -x '"\e[1;3D":pushd . > /dev/null && cd ..'
bind -x '"\e[1;3C":popd > /dev/null'
```

This works, but the current working directory in PS1 is not evaluated since no carriage return is entered. Is there a way to force bash to reevaluate PS1 in line?

Comment: You want it to redisplay the prompt even though you haven't executed a command?

Comment: I have executed a command, through bind.

Comment: What if you add `& echo -n ""` to the end of your bind?

Comment: Nope, does not help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200800/in-bash-how-do-i-bind-a-function-key-to-a-command

Comment: @xxfelixxx this answers how to bind a command. I did that, and it works. See my comment to your answer.

Comment: `pushd ..` should do the same thing as `pushd . && cd ..`.

Answer (score 0):

Following along with the accepted answer of [in-bash-how-do-i-bind-function-key-to-a-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200800/in-bash-how-do-i-bind-a-function-key-to-a-command), it looks like removing the `-x` and adding a `\n` at the end should do it:

```
bind '"\e[1;3D":"pushd . >/dev/null && cd .. && echo\n"'
bind '"\e[1;3C":"popd > /dev/null && echo -n\n"'
```

Comment: It does not really do what I want because it displays the command and then add a carriage return. But I'd like to do that without displaying the command and add a carriage return. I'd like to make the change inline for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: Thanks, fixed.  I could not find any other way of forcing bash to reissue the $PS1 prompt.

Comment: me neither, that's why I am asking ;)