# How to map the alt-keys on the command line

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal

I'm using Cygwin and followed the post at [In bash, how do I bind a function key to a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200800/in-bash-how-do-i-bind-a-function-key-to-a-command)

I used `Ctrl-v` to determine the mapping of some keys (e.g. `alt-h` is `^[h`).

As a result, I put `"^[h":backward-word` in my `.inputrc` but it doesn't work.

Other mappings for control-keys work, but not for alt-keys.

Comment: Are you actually putting in the SINGLE `^[` character?  (In `vi`, you can put it in with `Ctrl-v[`.

Comment: Wow I would have never guessed that. Thanks! If you want to put that as the answer I would love to give you credit @Jack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `vi` to edit your `.inputrc` file, and then enter the `^[` character with `Ctrl-v[` while in *insert* mode.

Comment: Need to hold the `Ctrl` key until pressed both `v` and `[`. I wrongly released in the middle and not work.

Answer (score 1):

You may also write `"\eh": backward-word` (in .inputrc), which bind the key `Alt-h`.