# What is the bindkey equivalent to bind -x?

Tags: zsh

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4201274/241142), the inimitable Dennis Williamson mentions how to bind a keystroke to a command that will run in the background of the Bash shell, with `bind -x`.  How can the same thing be done in Zsh?

(I couldn't find this in the `zshzle` man page, but it's possible that I overlooked it.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zle -M` to display info underneath your command line. For example:

```
.who() {
  zle -M "$(who)"
}

# Create a new widget `who` that calls our function `.who`.
zle -N who .who

# Bind said widget to alt-shift-W.
bindkey '^[W' who
```