# How to find out keystroke bash associated textual representation?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-18.04, keystroke, gnome-terminal

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4201148/2989289) is possible to map keystrokes to commands in a terminal. And to do this, there is a specific bash syntax for describes each key, as `\e[11~` for <kbd>F1</kbd> or `Control-o` for <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>

How not everyone is deductible, I would like to find a way to discover each key associated string. If I just press it in terminal nothing happens for most of non-alphanumeric keys

Comment: Bash manual on [Command Line Editing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Line-Editing) and especially on [Bindable Readline Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bindable-Readline-Commands).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can alternatively install expect, start autoexpect and see what are the codes for your key strokes in generated file.